# Having React Native build issues on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, reactjs, react-native

We are using RN .19 and react-native-vector-icons and building using the following script:

$ react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle

The app works great in the xcode simulator and behaves as expected. When I initially build on to my iPhone6 it remains running and works well, but when I restart the app from the phone or stop the app on my phone from xcode, the app shows redboxes for the icons.

I have tried re-cloning and install into different directories just so the xcode cache isn't an issue but it continues to happen.

Any ideas what is happening? It is very frustrating.

- Alright even more findings:

When i'm building directly on my iphone and code signing with my developer profile, code-push works and everything is fine

With my distribution signing profile (used in TestFlight) the build does not work properly

Answer (score 0):

It was a version inconsistency issue. Remember to make sure that codepush deploy and app ver numbers coincide.